# How to pass iterated string values to a function which accepts parametres of different type

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, iterator

Can some explain/tell me the solution of this ....Here the code sample goes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
      queue = new Queue<String>();
      set = new SET<String>();
      ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NO_OF_THREADS);                       
      List<Future<List<String>>> list = new ArrayList<Future<List<String>>>();  
      System.out.println("enter the url");
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      String input=sc.next();
      l.add(input);
      queue.enqueue(input);
      Callable<List<String>> worker = new SimpleCrawler(input);       
      Future<List<String>> submit = executor.submit(worker);        
      list.add(submit);
      ArrayList<?> l1=(ArrayList<?>) submit.get();
      Iterator<?> itr=l1.iterator();

      while(itr.hasNext())
         {
             System.out.println(itr.next());        
         }
```

How can i pass iterated string again to function submit(...).I want pass first iterated string to function and next iterated value to that function and so  on.....can some explain me this ..thanks

Comment: This is your fourth question. You should be getting the hang of formatting it correctly by now.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear from your question what you want to achieve, but why don't you just create a new `SimpleCrawler` with your iterated string and pass it to the same executor e.g.

```
while(itr.hasNext()) {
  Callable<List<String>> nextWorker = new SimpleCrawler(itr.next().toString())
  Future<List<String>> nextSubmit = executor.submit(nextWorker)
  ...
}
```